# Upgrading Ubuntu Server to a recent version would update PHP too? This result in any problems?

Tags: server, upgrade, php

I use Ubuntu Server 10.04 and PHP 5.3.2, if I upgrade the server to a more recent version, the PHP would update too? Would this process result in some problem in the settings of PHP, like previously installed extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an upgrade from 10.04 to, say, 12.04 will also upgrade PHP. The PHP version packaged for 12.04 is 5.3.10. If all extensions are installed from the repos, the upgrade shouldn't create problems in terms of PHP functionality *per se*.

But such an upgrade can create issues with web applications that may use specific functionality. My advise would be to set up a test server with 12.04 and try there any web applications running in the old server before upgrading.